# Cannot build project because of error in Android studio

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

i have the following error:

[image]

Build gradle file is following:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

 android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.bln.smc"
    minSdkVersion 18
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
 }
}

dependencies {
  compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
  testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
  compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
  compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.6.0'
  compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.6.0'
  compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:11.6.0'
  compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:11.6.0'
  compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.6.0'
  compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.6.0'
  compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.3'
  compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:1.2.0'
  compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
  compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.0.1'
 }
// Add to the bottom of the file
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

I researched a little bit and i think that the settings in the gradle file are ok.
So how can i solve this problem?

Comment: change SDK version to the last version of android build tools SDK (26) then clean and make your project again (remove all build files manually from the project). I have the same problem with 23.0.3 sometimes and I don't know why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you have conflicted dependencies in your `build.gradle`. Firebase UI need version 25 of support library but your dependencies is giving it version 23 instead.

If you want to use `firebase-ui:1.2.0`, you at least need to use support library version `25.1.1`. Take a look at [firebase-ui 1.2.0 build.gradle](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/version-1.2.0/constants.gradle).

Then, you also need to use a **compatible** Firebase/Google Play Service version. For `firebase-ui:1.2.0` you need to use Firebase/Google Play service version `10.2.0`.

My suggestion is to use the latest configuration. Something like this:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
  compileSdkVersion 26
  buildToolsVersion "26.0.2"

  defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.bln.smc"
    minSdkVersion 18
    targetSdkVersion 26
    ...
  }
  ...
}

dependencies {
  compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
  testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

  compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
  compile 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
  compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.1.0'
  // This is needed for firebase UI
  compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0'
  compile 'com.android.support:customtabs:26.1.0'
  compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.1.0'

  compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.4.2'
  compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.4.2'
  compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:11.4.2'
  compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:11.4.2'
  compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.4.2'
  compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.4.2'
  compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:3.1.0'
  compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
}

// Add to the bottom of the file
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```